# Implement Next, Previous, and GOTO using AngularJS. The PHP version DONE

Tags: angularjs, navigation, goto

I am working on a CBT app powered by (Laravel5)PHP and MySQL and data stored and fetched from the SESSION which has navigations such as next, previous, and goto. They are working on page refresh. How best can I use angularjs to do this without refreshing the page?

Thank you for responses in advance. I need your expert advice before doing anything.

Comment: Hey Saidi, please review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question is too-broad, and you haven't provided much info, but if you make vague questions, you'll get vague answers, so here we go.

I also developed an app with Laravel 5, and had a pagination with next / previous links. I used AJAX to make a call to the next page, and return the HTML into the current page.

```
$(document).on("click", ".pagination a", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    url = $(this).attr('href') + " #search_results-listing";
    $("#search_results").load(url, function() {
        setGetParameter('page', '2');
    });
});
```

Comment: @ Syla, thanks for your response. I mean the application currently working such that when a next/previous button is clicked, the app fetches saved data from session and populate it on the same page. Now the main idea here is that I do not want to have a page refresh before loading the requested content. I think I can do this with jquery. But I am willing to using angularJS instead of jquery. So I need someone to help me on the login and what directives, services or module to create in order to implement the same thing described above using without page refresh.